# Why does GE Plugin (6.2.1.6014) Crash on Refresh while executing fetchKml but only in ie9

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I have been using some fairly plain vanilla JavaScript code to load KML into a GE Plugin.  It still works normally in Windows 7 FireFox and Chrome and, until I was upgraded to IE9 worked in IE. Now I get the message: "There Was a Problem With the Google Earth Plugin ..." when I reload a page or load another similar page.

I have used the IE F12 Debugger tools to try to isolate the problem.  It always occurs when I am executing the fetchKml function to load a kmz file.  The ge plugin always crashes executing the statement:

windows.earth.TermsOfUseManager.prototype.db = function(){var = ...., c=a.a.getTermOfUseX_(),

I have a PDF file with a screen grab and other info.

I believe there must be an interaction between IE9 and the latest GE plugin.

The URL of a page with this problem is: 
http://reynsoft.com/Travel/Gallery/Baltic_2012/Day_2_At_Sea/Day_2_At_Sea.aspx

I hope someone out there can help.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the plugin? and are using the same 'bit' version of IE (ie have you gone from 32bit to 32bit or up to 64)

Comment: I have reinstalled it multiple times.  I am now using the 64 bit version of Windows 7.  I have just rebuilt my system.  That's something to think about.

Comment: the plugin only supports 32bit IE (but Windows 7 64bit is okay) - just not IE 64bit - http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166094 - otherwise check your video card driver - btw it works for me Win7 64bit and IE9

Comment: I just tried using our 32 bit Dell Laptop.  The problem still occurs, but less frequently.  There was a crash 5 times in 30 trials vs. 20 times in 30 on my desk top.  There were no crashes with a new browser 10 times our of 10. The interval between trials does not seem to matter.  I waited 2 minutes and still got a crash.

The mystery continues.  The video card software is up to date, but I will see if there is something funny about the configuration.

Comment: I believe this is a bug with Google Earth itself. I have a large app that uses GE as a mapping window -- and we see that issue frequently. We've actually decided to keep with the older version which doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Google Earth plugin requires explicit declaration of IE9 compatibility mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Simply, grab the [Sample](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index) from Google Earth documentation and add this line in `<head>` to see the difference in behaviour (alternatively, hit F12 and force *IE9 standards* mode).

Note, switching off the "Enhanced Protected Mode" in IE10 does not help.